# How to get exact item one by one from a request data?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests

Following is an output from a get request:

```
"ip": "8.8.8.8",

"city": "Mountain View",

"region": "California",

"country": "US",

"loc": "37.3860,-122.0838",

"postal": "94035",

"timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
```

How to break them to different variables?

For example I need to get 8.8.8.8 from  "ip": "8.8.8.8" and need to print

Is there an easy way doing that? I am doing a harder way and its impossible in some cases

Comment: what do you mean by "cut them". do you want these keys to be removed from the response?

Comment: try ```resp.json().get('ip')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume, the output is in a variable called response & is of form json or dictionary, then

```
ip = response.pop('ip')
city = response.pop('city')
```

and so on

if the response is not in dict format, then use get operation

```
ip = response.get('ip')
city = response.get('city')
```

Comment: `pop` is not necessary, `get` will do the job. op does not want to remove these keys from the dictionary.

Comment: targetip = resp.get('ip')
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: resp = reqs.get(url)
    alldata = resp.json()
    
    targetIP = alldata.get('ip')   WORKED thanks

Comment: Thank you both @Ajay A and Vishal Singh

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for fetching data using request and reading response into variables:

```
response = request.get(url)
if response:                    #<-- If response is in 200-299 range: True
    resp_data=response.json()   #<-- Convert output JSON stream into python readable object dict
    ip     = resp_data.get('ip')   #<-- .get function to avoid key error
    city   = resp_data.get('city')
    region = resp_data.get("region")
else:
    print(f"Error Occurred with Status Code {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Error : {response.text}")
```

1. Make Sure you check the status code on every request.get operation, when request fails data will not be returned.
2. Even if response is successful, you need to convert json output to python readable dicts using `response.json()`.
3. Use `dict.get("<dict_key>")` function to fetch variable to avaoid key error.

Comment: @GHOSTH4CK3R, If this answers your question. Mark this as useful and correct answer.